# Android custom toolbar title text not centering on Android 4.4 devices

Tags: android-toolbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I have created a custom toolbar for my app. But for some reason yet unknown to me on my android 4.4 KitKat devices the vertical centered text are not centered correctly. On a all android 5+ devices it works just fine.

It seems like on 4.4 to bottom (instead of the center) of the text of a textView is alligned with the center of the toolbar.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Here to xml in case you would like to see:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            tools:background="@color/background_default">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_icon_left_container"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_icon_left_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/back"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:fontFamily="@font/museo700"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar_icon_left_container"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar_text_right"
    style="@style/TextStyle5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_icon_left_container"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:text="Selecteer een leverdatum"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_text_right"
    style="@style/TextStyle7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/screen_edge_margin"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    tools:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    tools:text="Help"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it: the textStyle contained a value for **lineSpacingExtra**

```
<item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">10sp</item>
```

Which caused the TextView to add an extra margin at the bottom of the TextView only thus not centering text correctly in toolbar.

This only happened on KitKat & Lollipop devices where not affected by this.